# How to extract items inside JSON one by one with regex condition

Tags: python, json

I use Google Vision API on my project. The OCR result returns a JSON file that represents all the items the API recognized with coordinates. I want to add a feature that runs through the whole JOSN to find the item I want and then store the coordinate and the description into an array/list.

This is the returned JSON format:

```
{
  "textAnnotations": [
    {
      "description": "a",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 235,
            "y": 409
          },
          {
            "x": 247,
            "y": 408
          },
          {
            "x": 250,
            "y": 456
          },
          {
            "x": 238,
            "y": 457
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "b",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 235,
            "y": 409
          },
          {
            "x": 247,
            "y": 408
          },
          {
            "x": 250,
            "y": 456
          },
          {
            "x": 238,
            "y": 457
          }
        ]
      }
    },{c...},{d...},{e...}
  ],
  "fullTextAnnotation": {
    "pages": "not important",
    "text": "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n"
  }
}
```

My aim is to find 2 items and calculate whether they are parallel. For example, I want to find out b or c or d or e is parallel with a, and I have already stored the coordinate of a into a list with this method:

```
def getJson():
    try:
        f = open('json_file.json', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
        string = f.read()
        origin_data = json.loads(string)
        return origin_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(traceback.format_exc())

def get_keywords_coordinates(origin_data):

    __nodes = [__node for __node in origin_data['textAnnotations'] if __node['description'] == "a"]
    __keyword_coords = []
    for __lv in range(0, 4):
        __tempx = __node['boundingPoly']['vertices'][__lv]['x']
        __keyword_coords.append(__tempx)
        __tempy = __node['boundingPoly']['vertices'][__lv]['y']
        __keyword_coords.append(__tempy)

    return __keyword_coords
```

which keyword_coords is the list that contains the coordinate, which looks like this:

```
keyword_coords[235, 409, 247, 408, 250, 456, 238, 457]
```

I will put it and another keyword coordinate into a function to do that calculation but I have no idea how to get the coordinate of b, c, d, and e one by one (abcde is just an example, the real situation will not be able to define the item name with hard code. I may let the program finds out the keywords with some regex)

How should I deal with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you wanting to choose which polygon you are comparing the others against by name or can it be by index?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Why not use loop `for item in origin_data['textAnnotations']` to work with every item  one by one. Eventually in loop use `if item['description'] != "a"` to skip item `a`. And I don't understand why you ask for `regex`. It doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do but it doesn't need regex but normal `for`-loop to work with items one by one.

First I would change `get_keywords_coordinates` to get all items and coordinates

```
def get_keywords_coordinates(data):

    results = []
    
    for item in data['textAnnotations']:
        key = item["description"]
        coords = []
        for point in item["boundingPoly"]['vertices']:
            coords.append(point['x'])
            coords.append(point['y'])
        results.append( (key, coords) )
        
    return results

results = get_keywords_coordinates(data)

print('--- coords ---')
print(results)
```

Result:

```
--- coords ---
[
  ('a', [235, 409, 247, 408, 250, 456, 238, 457]), 
  ('b', [335, 409, 347, 408, 350, 456, 338, 457]), 
  ('c', [435, 409, 447, 408, 450, 456, 438, 457])
]
```

And I would get some selected itme (i.e. first item with `a`) and create list without this item

```
selected = results[0]
#rest = results[1:]
rest = results.copy()  # more useful if I would selected item with different index
rest.remove(selected)  # more useful if I would selected item with different index

print('--- items ---')
print('selected:', selected)
print('rest    :', rest)
print('---')
```

Result:

```
--- items ---
selected: ('a', [235, 409, 247, 408, 250, 456, 238, 457])
rest    : [('b', [335, 409, 347, 408, 350, 456, 338, 457]), ('c', [435, 409, 447, 408, 450, 456, 438, 457])]
```

And I could use `for`-loop to compare selected item with other items - one by one

```
for item in rest:
    print('compare', selected[0], 'with', item[0])
    print(selected[0], selected[1])
    print(item[0], item[1])
```

Result:

```
compare a with b
a [235, 409, 247, 408, 250, 456, 238, 457]
b [335, 409, 347, 408, 350, 456, 338, 457]
compare a with c
a [235, 409, 247, 408, 250, 456, 238, 457]
c [435, 409, 447, 408, 450, 456, 438, 457]
```

---

Full example:

```
data = {
  "textAnnotations": [
    {
      "description": "a",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 235,
            "y": 409
          },
          {
            "x": 247,
            "y": 408
          },
          {
            "x": 250,
            "y": 456
          },
          {
            "x": 238,
            "y": 457
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "b",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 335,
            "y": 409
          },
          {
            "x": 347,
            "y": 408
          },
          {
            "x": 350,
            "y": 456
          },
          {
            "x": 338,
            "y": 457
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "c",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 435,
            "y": 409
          },
          {
            "x": 447,
            "y": 408
          },
          {
            "x": 450,
            "y": 456
          },
          {
            "x": 438,
            "y": 457
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  ],
  "fullTextAnnotation": {
    "pages": "not important",
    "text": "a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n"
  }
}

def get_keywords_coordinates(data):

    results = []
    
    for item in data['textAnnotations']:
        key = item["description"]
        coords = []
        for point in item["boundingPoly"]['vertices']:
            coords.append(point['x'])
            coords.append(point['y'])
        results.append( (key, coords) )
        
    return results

results = get_keywords_coordinates(data)

print('--- coords ---')
print(results)

selected = results[0]
#rest = results[1:]
rest = results.copy()
rest.remove(selected)

print('--- keywords ---')
print('selected:', selected)
print('rest    :', rest)
print('---')
      
for item in rest:
    print('compare', selected[0], 'with', item[0])
    print(selected[0], selected[1])
    print(item[0], item[1])
```